# For automatic C# code generation: ApexSql Code or Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, code-generation

I want to generate C# code automatically, for data access in my asp.net projects. Which of the approaches (also why) is more suitable for automatic C# code generation: Entity Framework or ApexSql Code?

Please note that I'll be updating db model from time to time. I want to do this with minimal effort (e.g. without need to run a sql diff tool if possible).

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but I don't think ApexSql has code generation like `EF`.  From what you have mentioned, it sounds like you want EF Code First.

[Code-First Development with Entity Framework 4](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx)

Comment: I was thinking using the model first approach. For apex part, "ApexSql Code" can be used for code generation:
http://www.apexsql.com/help/apexsqlcode/html/Code.htm#ApexSQL_Code_Application_Window.htm

Comment: Does EF create any stored procedures? Or is it not necessary thanks to linq??

Comment: Not sure, but I have used LLBLGen Pro before and it does any and everything. NHibernate is a good tool as well.

Comment: @ace: EF isn't a "code generator" - it's a database **access** technology. EF can use stored procedures - but it doesn't create any